# Get only specific values in array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to get only two objects in the resultant array with label `one` and label `two`.
How do I filter values in an array of objects. Could anyone please help?

```js
const arr = [{
    value: "1",
    label: "one"
  },
  {
    value: "2",
    label: "two"
  },
  {
    value: "3",
    label: "three"
  },
];

arr.map((val, index) => val.filter(val.label => val.label === 'one' && val.label === 'two'))

console.log(arr)
```

I was expecting an output like this below

```
[{
    value: "1",
    label: "one"
  },
  {
    value: "2",
    label: "two"
  },
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the label is either "one" **or** (not and) "two" with just [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) (you don't need `map`).

```js
const arr = [{
    value: "1",
    label: "one"
  },
  {
    value: "2",
    label: "two"
  },
  {
    value: "3",
    label: "three"
  },
];

const res = arr.filter(val => val.label === 'one' || val.label === 'two');

console.log(res)
```

If there are multiple labels you want to allow, you can use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to store them, and use [`Set#has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) for filtering.

```js
const arr = [{
    value: "1",
    label: "one"
  },
  {
    value: "2",
    label: "two"
  },
  {
    value: "3",
    label: "three"
  },
  {
    value: "4",
    label: "four"
  },
  {
    value: "5",
    label: "five"
  },
  {
    value: "6",
    label: "six"
  },
  {
    value: "7",
    label: "seven"
  }
];
const allowedLabels = new Set(["one", "two", "four", "seven"]);
const res = arr.filter(val=>allowedLabels.has(val.label));
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to change your condition as a 'OR' (`||` instead of `&&`), because one particular element cannot have label that is, at the same time, both 'one' *and* 'two'.

You want that a particular element has label that is *either* 'one' *or* 'two'

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want to do this -

```
arr.filter((obj) => obj.label == "one" || obj.label == "two");
```

Answer (score 0):

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass
> the test implemented by the provided function.

You don't have to use map. You can directly filter you array using `filter()` which takes a function(that will be take each element of the array as parameter) and returns a new array with only the elements that matches the specified condition of the function.

You can do it as follows -

```js
const arr = [{
    value: "1",
    label: "one"
  },
  {
    value: "2",
    label: "two"
  },
  {
    value: "3",
    label: "three"
  },
];


let filtered_arr = arr.filter((obj)=> obj.label==='one' || obj.label==='two');

console.log(filtered_arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the filter method:

```
arr.filter(obj => ((obj.label=="one")||(obj.label=="two")))
```